# Can predictive power be inferred from only in-sample modelling results?

Tags: forecasting, prediction

I wonder if one can tell anything about predictive power of a model if model selection and estimation was done using all available data. That is, there was no data left for "out of sample" prediction trials. (In other words, data was not split into a "training sample" to select and estimate the model and a "test/holdout sample" to examine forecasting performance.)

In other words, can predictive power be inferred from only in-sample modelling results?

Answer (score 4):

There are several subtle points I think you missed:

1. In a mechanistic world there may be a true model (e.g., Newtonian mechanics) but it other situations this is very unlikely.  Instead one usually finds that when more and better data become available one can get a better model.  BIC assumes there is a single true model.
2. Selecting a model according to the best BIC is a biased process that will result in overfitting.
3. $R_{adj}^2$ was designed to de-bias an ordinary $R^2$ in a linear model when there is a *single pre-specified* model.

I believe that the only thing you can assume is that if your sample is very large and is representative of the future to which you want to apply a forecast, the apparent $R^2$ is an upper bound of the real $R^2$.

Comment: Great answer! Let me see if I understand you arguments. (1): I appreciate the possibility that the "true" model may have evolved over time. Is this what you mean by more & better data -> better model? If so, we should denote this time-dependent model as the "true" model. (Surely, there must have been a process that generated the data - we call it the "true" process - regardless of what we know about it. It might have been a very complex one, of course, so it might be missing in the pool of our candidate models.) If so, there is nothing wrong with BIC assuming a single true model.

Comment: (2): Model selection by BIC is biased because the choice between all k-parameter models in the pool of candidate models is due to explanatory power. That is, BIC does data mining (data snooping?) inside the set of k-parameter models, for each k. Other than that, BIC is consistent. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: (3) I would only use R^2_adj for the ultimately selected model. If I was certain that the model selection procedure was sound, it would make sense to use R^2_adj, wouldn't it? Again, the R^2_adj would not be used in the model selection stage, but only in the last stage to assess the properties of the ultimate model.

Comment: In the last paragraph, would it be correct to use the apparent R^2_adj, not apparent R^2, as an upper bound of the real R^? I think so because R^2_adj is the unbiased and weakly consistent estimator of the population R^2 as noted in the original question.

Comment: Don't write a bunch of separate comments.  $R_{adj}^{2}$ is *not* for an "ultimately selected model".  It is for a *single pre-specified* model.  BIC, if there were to be one true model, can help you select the most probable model.  The probability that this model is the true model may still be 0.01 and the resulting selected model can be terribly overfitted.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got the point on R^2_adj. The key is pre-testing (or however one should call it); the R^2_adj of the "ultimately selected model" would suffer from it. (The result would be conditional on the model selection stage.) I still do not get why BIC-selection is a biased process in the case when a true model exists. Even if BIC may overfit on a particular occasion, it may underfit, too - that is no surprise. What counts is that on average BIC is consistent in terms of model selection. Otherwise why would we say that BIC is a consistent criterion? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to answer the heart of your question, but BIC can be written as a function of $P$-values and $R^2$ and model selection based on those are unlikely to have good calibration due to overfitting (regression to the mean).  Again, if the probability of correctness of the model having the highest probability of being "right" is only 0.01, you have a problem.

Comment: Point (2) in the answer above seems doubtful, if not wrong. Burnham & Anderson "Understanding AIC and BIC in model selection" (DOI: 10.1177/0049124104268644) section 3 indicates that BIC-selection typically _underfits_ in small samples. As sample size increases, BIC-selected model approaches the so-called target model from below (i.e. underfits rather than overfits). The target model is the model from the pool of all models considered that is closest to the "true" model in terms of Kullback-Leibler information. (By the way, "true" model need not be in the pool for this to hold.)

Comment: You are correct.  BIC significantly underfits, which is why I never use it in the first place.

Comment: You need not be sceptical of BIC because it underfits. It does so for a good reason. If the true model has many parameters while the sample is small, estimation precision of the many parameters will be low -> "high variance". If a simpler model is estimated instead, some bias will be introduced due to the omitted regressors -> "high bias"; meanwhile, the variance due to estimation will be smaller. Thus we have a trade-off between bias and variance. BIC does account for it in a sensible way. It penalizes the number of parameters depending on sample size to achieve a good bias-variance balance.

Comment: In my experience BIC does not meet its goal.  This is most pronounced when solving for an optimal shrinkage parameters - BIC will over-shrink making the calibration on future data poor from too much under-fitting.  I am still troubled about the use of BIC to select from a large number of competing models.  I think this will at least result in over-interpretation, and it will not compete with a penalized "super model" that is a superset of all the models entertained.